# What is the django ORM query for this sql query?

Tags: postgresql, django-orm

Can this query be translated to Django ORM. This works in postgresql.

```
select * from user_feed_moderation 
left join user_feed_moderator on mod_id=user_id 
where 
    is_mod_available=false and 
    is_moderated = false order 
by created_on
```

currently I am forced to run a raw sql query in django.

These are my models

```
class Moderator(models.Model):
    is_mod_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField()

class Moderation(TimeStampedModel):
    mod_id          = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    post_id         = models.BigIntegerField()
    content_type    = models.CharField(max_length = 3, choices=ContentTypes.choices)
    is_moderated    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Share your related models.

Comment: You did not use a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes I didn't want to create a dependency in the database. Can it still be done?